# Get notification of a file that is being deleted from SD card in Android

Tags: android, recycle-bin, fileobserver

I am using `FileObserver` to get notification for deleted file.I want to save all deleted file from sd card(like Dumpster app) before deletion. But I get notification after the file has deleted but i want just before deletion so that I can save this file some where else that can be restored later just like dumpster android app( [Dumpster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baloota.dumpster&hl=en) ) . How to do this?  I am using this code which gives me info about deleted file.

```
public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
    if (path == null) {
        return;
    }
    //a file was deleted from the monitored directory
    if ((FileObserver.DELETE & event)!=0) {
        //If Here I want to copy File some where else then I am getting 'File Not found exception'

}
```

}

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555697/how-can-i-notify-my-application-that-one-file-was-deleted-from-the-sdcard-andro

Comment: @ridoy I think its not possible using Java code.It need C level programming.

Comment: do you succeeded to do this so far ?

Comment: @Victor I have dropped this project :( . But this is possible only through native programming(C).....